# Help with Django ORM query

Tags: django, orm, annotations

I have these two Django models (simplified):

```
class Movie(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    year = models.IntegerField(max_length=4)
    rating = models.DecimalField(max_digits=2, decimal_places=1, default=0)


class Request(models.Model):
    movie = models.ForeignKey(Movie)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    language = models.CharField(max_length=7, choices=settings.APP_LANGUAGES, db_index=True)
    notes = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    added = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
```

I want to get all Requests with a count by language for each movie. I actually come up with a solution with an ORM query, which gives me the results I am looking for:

`reqs = Request.objects.values('movie', 'langauge').annotate(Count('language'))`

However, I will need an access to other Movie attributes while I will be rendering the results in the template. Obviously, the above query returns ValueQuerySet like:

`[{'movie': 460, 'language__count': 1, 'language': u'es-mx'}, {'movie': 458, 'language__count': 2, 'language': u'cs'}, {'movie': 459, 'language__count': 1, 'language': u'el'}]`

Thus something like `reqs[0].movie.rating` won't work. So, how should I access other Movie attributes?

Thank you.

Comment: Is SubtitleRequest supposed to be the same model as Request?

Comment: yes, sorry for this inconsistency. Fixed

Comment: So, is there a problem with `reqs = Request.objects.annotate(Count('language')).select_related('movie')`?

Comment: @Mike DeSimon the problem with your query is that it doesn't group by language, i.e. I'd get language__count 1 for all results

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
reqs = Request.objects.values('movie', 'movie__rating', 'movie__title', 'movie__year', 'language').annotate(Count('language'))
print reqs
```

here is sample output:

```
[
    {'movie__year': 2010, 'language': u'EN', 'movie__title': u'Foo', 'movie': 1, 'language__count': 1, 'movie__rating': Decimal('1')}, 
    {'movie__year': 2010, 'language': u'ES', 'movie__title': u'Foo', 'movie': 1, 'language__count': 1, 'movie__rating': Decimal('1')}, 
    {'movie__year': 2010, 'language': u'RU', 'movie__title': u'Foo', 'movie': 1, 'language__count': 1, 'movie__rating': Decimal('1')}, 
    {'movie__year': 1998, 'language': u'EN', 'movie__title': u'Bar', 'movie': 2, 'language__count': 3, 'movie__rating': Decimal('9')}, 
    {'movie__year': 1998, 'language': u'RU', 'movie__title': u'Bar', 'movie': 2, 'language__count': 1, 'movie__rating': Decimal('9')}, 
]
```

you can see that returning extra movie attributes doesn't change the count, here is sample  output from your original query:

```
reqs = Request.objects.values('movie', 'language').annotate(Count('language'))
print reqs
```

this produces output:

```
[
    {'movie': 1, 'language__count': 1, 'language': u'EN'}, 
    {'movie': 1, 'language__count': 1, 'language': u'ES'}, 
    {'movie': 1, 'language__count': 1, 'language': u'RU'}, 
    {'movie': 2, 'language__count': 3, 'language': u'EN'}, 
    {'movie': 2, 'language__count': 1, 'language': u'RU'}, 
]
```

**EDIT**

If you want to be able to call methods on the *movie* then you want to select the *movies* with you query, not the *requests*:

```
movies = Movie.objects.annotate(num_lang=Count('request__language')).all()
```

This will return all the movies, annotated by request's language count, which you can access via property *num_lang* on the movie. You will also be able to call all the methods on the movies objects

Comment: No, because all those fields will be considered part of the GROUP BY.

Comment: @Daniel Roseman, actually that's works just fine. The reason is that the 'movie' returns the id, which already uniquely identifies the movie. If we return any extra attributes for the movie, it is not going to affect the "group by". I've added sample output.

Comment: OK, this is quite good - seems to work the way I need. But is there some way so that I will be able to access Movie methods as well? I guess I would need to use `reqs = Request.objects.values('movie', 'language').annotate(Count('language'))` and then select Movies where `id__in=[r.movie for r in reqs]`, and then somehow map those together. But I don't know what would be an optimal way to do such mapping - any ideas?

Comment: @danger, I've updated my answer to show how you can call Movie methods. Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks; I have been there, but that one doesn't actually return counts *per* language and I still need an access to the value of language without making N db queries (select_related() wouldn't work there, I guess). So I still think I need to do my mapping manually and I haven't come to something optimal yet.